# In App Purchases keep crashing Test Flight

Tags: swift, swiftui, storekit

I am trying to test my In-App Purchases that work in the simulator but not in Test Flight. I am not sure why but my question is could it be possible that I didn't fill in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking information under the agreements section?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-App Purchase Is Crashing When Trying to Buy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324569/in-app-purchase-is-crashing-when-trying-to-buy)

Comment: Did you remove your StoreKit Configuration file from the Scheme before archiving your app?

Comment: @CALL-151 No...

Comment: @CALL-151 Can that be the problem?

Comment: Yes. The configuration file will prevent your app from using a sandbox account.

Comment: @CALL-151 I removed the config file and the app still crashed in test flight, any other reason?

Comment: Many...You'll need to inspect your crash logs and ask a much more specific question for someone on SO to help. It might help to start by reviewing https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb57be10e7

Comment: @CALL-151 I dint sign the banking and tax agreement yet, could that be a reason that it doesn't work in test flight?

Comment: Yes. There's only one way to find out if that's causing your problem...